Отправка сообщений на GMail через PHP
Я создаю сайт, в котором человек должен внести электронную почту и на нее получить чек. Но Google не дает стороннему приложению отправить сообщение на почту без App Password. Как это реализовать, использую mail()?

Вы что-то путаете, для отправки email при помощи функции mail() не требуется никаких "App Password" можете отправлять email хоть на gmail, хоть куда угодно, письмо конечно может попасть в спам, но это уже другой вопрос.

Если принципиально отправлять с gmail, юзайте PhpMailer.

GMail требует, чтобы была включена аутентификация SPF или DKIM. https://support.google.com/a/topic/9061731?hl=en&ref_topic=9202&sjid=4981864215330757294-EU
Нужно добавить соответствующие записи в ваши настройки почты.
